# ag grid headerCheckBoxSelection

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I've added headerCheckBoxSelection to my ag grid.
I would like to dynamically control on when the headerCheckBoxSelection will appear so I'm using this as a function

```
headerCheckboxSelection: (params) => {
    
}
```

Inside this method, I would like to call the parent component from the context that I'm passing into the aggrid options.

```
gridOptions["context"]= {parentComponent : this }
```

However, when I try to log the context, it is undefined. Is context available for headerCheckboxSelection?

I was expecting that context will be available inside headerCheckboxSelection according to the documentations https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/